# Grab the JSON response success status message and stored in DB in php MySQL

Tags: php, json, curl

I had a curl request to post a data to external system, the curl will response the success true/false message after curl process finished, and return the success responses

```
{"success":false,"error":{"code":"Accounts:-3","message":"[Invalid Post Title]"}}
```

Within this response I want to store `"message":"[Invalid Post Title]"` into my response_state field, but so far the insert not expected.

what so far i tried to achieve this

**First**

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
........
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$results = json_decode($result->error[0]->message);
```

all this value inserted DB:

```
{"success":false,"error":{"code":"Accounts:-3","message":"[Invalid Post Title]"}}
```

**Second**

```
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$results = utf8_encode($result,true);
```

I got error 500

here the query for insert

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die ("Connection Failed")
$mysqli  = "INSERT INTO log (userid, status) 
VALUES ('$userid', '$status')";
```

Really appreciate for any comment or tutorial link, try to explore on net but still cannot found.

Thank

Comment: That response is not valid JSON.

Comment: is it possible cause by multiple curl to different api?

Comment: Hi @PatrickQ, i edit my php file to make json response valid, for now I just call one uri curl. but still no luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: Now that you have valid JSON, this is a duplicate

Comment: thanks for that links, but the json response return with the '1' at the end. {"success":false,"error":{"code":"Accounts:-3","message":"[Invalid Post Title]"}}1

Comment: tried something like this not data show :

`$json = '{"success":false,"error":{"code":"Accounts:-3","message":"[Invalid KK Number]"}}';

$yummy = json_decode($json, true);

echo $yummy['error'][1]['code'];
`

Comment: `var_dump($yummy);` and you should see why `$yummy['error'][1]` isn't correct

Comment: i will take  a look on another sample, since I am new, really no idea why always null or 1 number  :(

Comment: finally works with the manual embed data, but if i try to grab from curl it doesn't. so i tried to put CURLOPT_ENCODING => "UTF-8", and works perfectly, Thanks for clue @PatrickQ